# Clearing data of the textfields and textviews view on toggling of a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

Suppose I have a button and a view consisting multiple fields like textfields, textviews etc. There is some input data in the textfield as well as in textview. When I click on button the view gets hide, when i clicked again, it shows up. What I want is, when view reappear, all the input fields should be clear. I can clear the textfields data manually by setting it as `empty string (@"")` but I want some cleaner solution, which ll clear all the fields of view. I tried doing `self.toggleView = nil` too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Xcoder did you find my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option for doing this is

```
- (void)clearTextFieldOrTextViews{
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
      {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            textField = (UITextField*)subview;
            textField.text = @"";
        }else if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){
            textView = (UITextview*)subview;
            textView.text = @"";
        }else if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            button = (UIButton*)subview;
            [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: I have textfields, textviews, and buttons. I was searching for something which can clear the whole view data.

Comment: you want to remove textfields, textviews and buttons or you just want to remove text from them?

Comment: just want to clear the data from the field. But the point is, i don't wanna do it manually foe all fields.

Comment: You don't need to do it manually. Just call this method it will work for that view.